compiling graphical abstract in eps file format in Elsevier's CAS Latex Double-Column Template LaTeX package
I'm using Elsevier's CAS Latex Double-Column Template LaTeX package. There was a problem that I couldn't solve while writing the paper, so I posted this to ask experts for help. To include graphical abstract in the paper, while uploading graphical abstract.eps format, it does not appeared in the pdf of paper. if used graphical abstract.pdf format, it works. but i want to upload .eps version. All other figures can be able to upload in the .eps form in my paper except graphical abstract. The code I used is given below
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{graphicalabstract}
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{graphical abstract.eps}
\end{graphicalabstract}
\end{document}

Please help me to resolve this

pdftex can not include eps, so any eps have to be converted first to pdf it normally happens automatically (you do not need the epstopdf package) but if it failed there may be an error in your eps, but if you have a pdf version it is better to use that anyway as it saves the conversion step.

oh do not use a space in the filename.

Your example does not work, because of a missing title. After adding \title{Title} it fails, because the automatic conversion of graphical abstract.eps fails because of the space in the filename (see, e.g. this answer). After renaming the file to graphicalabstract.eps
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\begin{graphicalabstract}
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{graphicalabstract.eps}
\end{graphicalabstract}
\end{document}

it runs without error. But to show a result, it needs also a \maketitle:
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\begin{graphicalabstract}
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{graphicalabstract.eps}
\end{graphicalabstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}


Note: I've also removed the packages amsmath, graphicx, amssymb, because they are already loaded by the class. And I've remove epstopdf, because it is not needed to do the default automatic conversion from eps to pdf (unless you are using a very, very out-dated TeX installation).
